# Извлечь содержимое тега <Row> в XML

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Дан простой String

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s88" ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-1]&lt;&gt;&quot;&quot;,RC[-4]*RC[-1],&quot;&quot;)"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="Number">1467</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">        1-2501к люкс Сумка женская</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="Number">2165</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">23</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s88" ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-1]&lt;&gt;&quot;&quot;,RC[-4]*RC[-1],&quot;&quot;)"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="Number">1468</Data></Cell>
```

Не получается написать регулярное выражение между тегами ROW

```
"<Row>.*^(</Row>)</Row>"
```

Должно работать, но почему-то не работает.

Comment: А на кой чёрт вы используете regexp для этого?

Comment: А чтобы вы использовали? Обычный поиск? SAX?

Comment: SAX или DOM

Comment: Вообще, в любом случае, парсить XML с помощью regexp - это всегда грязный хак. Так что на самом деле не стоит даже думать о проблеме с regexp в данном случае.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
/<row>(.*)<\/row>/Uis
```

Пояснения:

(.*) - ищем от 0 до бесконечности символов

U - выключаем "жадность" регэкспов

i - выключаем case

s - забиваем на переносы строк

Comment: что за "жадность"?

Comment: Это когда есть
<pre>< b >asdqwe</ b > asd < b >ertret</ b ></pre>
то без U вернет
<pre>asdqwe</ b > asd < b >ertret</pre>, а вот с U вернет
<pre>asdqwe и ertret</pre>

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос
1) А что такое / ?
2) и почему .* в скобках?

Comment: Косая черта - это не для Java. Выкиньте их. А U вы не можете подсунуть таким способом. Надо регекспу в качестве опций передать. В скобках потому, что это та часть, котрую вы хотите получить, не так ли? Вот вы её и получите в чистом виде.

Comment: Ну я расписал регэксп в общем виде, как он идет для java понятия не имею :) Поэтому я расписал какая буква что означает :)